# Inserindo dados em SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Ola gostaria de saber como posso alterar código da área 1 de `insert` usando o `foreach($nome as $cod => $value)`  que nem o código da área 2 
não estou conseguindo fazer uma adaptação alterando o modo de `insert` do código 2 de forma que o `foreach($nome as $cod => $value)` funcione.

Código 1

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `episodios` SET `nome`='".$_POST["nome"]."',`media`='".$_POST["media"]."',`tamanho`='".$_POST["tamanho"]."',`tipo`='".$_POST["tipo"]."'")
```

Código 2

```
$nome = $_POST['nomes'];
$anime = $_POST['animes'];
$tamanho = $_POST['tamanhos'];
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];

foreach($nome as $cod => $value){
$sql = "insert into episodios (id,nome,anime,tamanho,tipo) values ('','$nome[$cod]','$anime[$cod]','$tamanho[$cod]','$tipo')";
$consulta = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if($consulta) {
echo "<br/><center><div id=\"Aviso_ok\">Episodio Cadastrado com Sucesso</div></center><br/>";
}else{
echo "<br/><center><div id=\"Aviso_erro\">Erro ao Cadastrar o Episodio</div></center><br/>";}
}
```

Comment: Qual é o problema? O que você não consegue fazer?

Comment: Também não estou a entender a dúvida.

Comment: estou querendo usar no caso o foreach($nome as $cod => $value) no código 1 só que não estou sabendo como fazer a adptação

Comment: É igual em vez de `$_POST["nome"]` usas o `$nome[$cod]`

Comment: Ata obrigada pela ajuda

Comment: cuidado com sqlinjection.

Comment: Só uma coisa alem de ter que por assim $nome[cod] eu tenho que por no caso o $nome = $_POST['nomes']; e os demais valores de post no código 1 uma vez que vou substituir os $_POST[' ']; no inicio do código 1 para que os valores de post sejam aplicados ?

Comment: Sim é isso mesmo

Comment: Olha como disse o @RuiLima tens de ter cuidado com SQL *injection*. Devias usar `mysqli_` em vez de `mysql_` e usar *prepared statements*.

Comment: Ok isso ai no caso evita o uso do havij ?

Comment: Podes usar na mesma para testar...

Comment: Só mais uma duvida quando e aplicado isso $nome[$cod] no código aplica o valor do $_POST["nome"] pegos da array certo ? Ai no caso daria para atuar como uma definição no where ex where nome='." $nome[$cod]".' de forma fizesse ai no exemplo ordenar itens pelo menos nome desde que esteja dentro do loop do foreach($nome as $cod => $value){ } do código em questão ?

Comment: noca caso assim o $select2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `listas` WHERE `nome`='".nome[cod]".'");
$dados2 = mysql_fetch_array($select2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para gerar um único INSERT, que insira todos os registros de uma vez, você precisa de uma sql neste formato:

```
INSERT INTO tabela(numero) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)
```

Isso equivale a isto:

```
INSERT INTO tabela(numero) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO tabela(numero) VALUES (2);
...
INSERT INTO tabela(numero) VALUES (10);
```

Para isso, use uma lógica parecida com esta:

```
$valores = range( 1 , 10 );
$sql = sprintf( 'INSERT INTO tabela(numero) VALUES (%s)', implode( '), (' , $valores ) );
```

Você vai gerar um único INSERT, deixando o sistema muito mais rápido

Veja mais neste artigo: http://rberaldo.com.br/inserindo-multiplos-registros-em-tabela-de-banco-de-dados/

Seu sistema tem dois outros problemas: SQL Injection e mysql.

1. Para se proteger conta SQL Injection, veja: http://rberaldo.com.br/seguranca-em-sistemas-de-login-protecao-contra-sql-injection/
2. funções mysql_* estão obsoletas desde o PHP 5.5. Prefira usar MySQLi ou PDO. Veja mais aqui: http://www.ultimatephp.com.br/php-por-que-nao-utilizar-funcoes-mysql

Comment: Não e bem isso que eu perguntei mais em todo caso estarei marcando a resposta como aceita pelo fato de você ter passado tutoriais bem úteis para mim desde já agradeço.